# What control is being used in the Settings app to edit signature

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What control is being used in the Settings app to edit mail signature and why is it not available in the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raise a bug report with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com/). As you note, it's not available in the SDK. We don't know why; we're not Apple.

Probably not what you want, but you'll need to put your signature editing preferences inside your app rather than in the Settings.

Comment: I don't need to edit signatures, I just need to edit text, was just wondering why Apple doesn't make that control available.  Will raise a bug.